# In the Sandbox test of StoreKit2 billing process, can I cancel a purchase of a Non-Consumable item?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-billing, storekit

I have recently started developing an IOS app in xcode.
I am implementing the billing process with Storekit2, but after purchasing a "non-consumable" item with a sandbox account, I am unable to cancel the purchase.

[The official site](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_at_all_stages_of_development_with_xcode_and_sandbox/) says that this is the case, but in order to test it, we would like to test the purchase process repeatedly in a sandbox environment that is similar to the production environment.
We have the following two tests for Storekit2, and we are aware that Storekit Configuration can be tested over and over again.

- Storekit Configuration
- Sandbox

1, Is there any way to cancel to buy in order to test billing over and over again?
2, In actual practice, do we try various cases with Storekit Configuration and if it is OK, we release it already?
3, Also, before the advent of Storekit Configuration, how did you test a "non-consumable" product multiple times?

If anyone has more information, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

TL,DR: learn more about Testing all stages with IAP [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_at_all_stages_of_development_with_xcode_and_sandbox)

Yes, you could do "Clear the purchase history" as it's listed

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77rl3.png)

1. Xcode enviroment

When you're running app from your Xcode on simulator or device, just click button Manage Storekit Transactions. Then you could test with any stage, refund or clear purchase history

[Manage Storekit Transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etTm0.png)

2. Sandbox
   Just login AppStoreConnect, Users and Access -> Select tab Sandbox Testers -> there is `Edit` button, just follow it to clear transaction history

[Sandbox Testers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rkEt.png)

Comment: Whaaaat, this is insane! Thank you for sharing <3